# Declare abstract class in c++

Tags: c++, abstract

How do i declare abstract class?

For example, I know it's using the keyword virtual like:

```
class test{
public:
virtual void test()=0;
}
```

My question is can I abstract test class like this? If not why and how

```
virtual class test{
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Having a class with no methods makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I want to confirm whether if i can declare a abstract class as stated above

Comment: It's not possible, and you should not want to do this. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is can I abstract test class like this?

No, you can't. An abstract class by definition is a class that contains at least one pure virtual function.

Answer (score 15):

In most cases, your abstract class contains abstract ("pure virtual" in C++ terms) methods:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

That is sufficient to make it an abstract class:

```
Foo foo; // gcc says: cannot declare variable 'foo' to be of abstract type 'Foo'
```

Note that you **really** want to declare the destructor as virtual in your base class, or you risk undefined behavior when destroying your derived object through a base class pointer.

There also might be cases when you have **no abstract methods**, but still want to mark your class as abstract. There are two ways:

a. Declare your base destructor as pure virtual:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() { }
};

Foo::~Foo() = default; // need to define or linker error occurs
```

b. Declare all your base constructors as protected:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void bar() { }

protected:
    Foo() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
class test
{
virtual void test()=0;
}
```

creates an abstract class.
it contains one or more pure virtual functions:

```
virtual void test()=0;//is a pure virtual function/method
```

An abstract class is a class definition that contains one or more pure virtual functions.

You can't create instances of an abstract class because it is not a complete definition.

Your code:

```
 virtual class test
{
    }
```

is nonsensical, does not rise to the definition of an abstract class because it does not contain one or more pure virtual function, and is an improper use of the 'virtual' keyword...

You may be confused by talk about "Virtual Base Classes" which is a misleading way of referring to the semantic of the "Abstract Class".

purpose for making an abstract class is to inherit it into derived class and there provide a full definition for the pure virtual function/s.

Abstract class could contain many fully defined methods but only one pure virtual method which would make it abstract.  The simplistic example is misleading.  Abstract classes are common and are often a "fix" for issues arising from the (Barbara) Liskov Substitution Principle.

Dr t