# E0322: object of abstract class type "" is not allowed

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have a pure virtual function in my header file and a static class instance:

```
static Class mInstance;
```

I get the following error:

> object of abstract class type "Class" is not allowed: function "" is a
>   pure virtual function.

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Some more details:

My wish is to use the mInstance variable in other non-derived classes. The pure virtual function is being overriden by derived classes. Can I ask what kind of details I should provide? The mInstance variable is being used with a FactoryMethod that I wrote.

Comment: As the error says, you're not allowed to create an abstract type.  We need more details on what your are trying to achieve in order to tell you how you could refactor the code.

Comment: you need to implement the function please add the class definition to your question

Comment: Share the definition for `Class`. Most likely, it has one or more abstract functions, or one of its base types is abstract and no one provided an implementation.

Comment: What is shown inside the quotes (that you redacted) should help you. You can't have an instance of your class because you did not implement the listed pure virtual functions.

Comment: I have edited my question. @drescherjm "Class:execute()" is between the quotes. This is the name of the pure virtual function.

Comment: If `Class` has one or more pure virtual functions, then an instance of that class cannot be created.  Either (1) make that function non-pure (i.e. remove the `=0` that makes the virtual function pure) or (2) derive a class from `Class`, have that derived class override that pure virtual member function, and create an instance of that derived class (e.g. change `static Class mInstance` to `static SomeDerivedClass mInstance`).

Comment: Unfortunately, the instance MUST be from Base class. I'm not sure but to me it seems that the functionality really changes upon applying the changes that are suggested. I really need not the functionality to change.

Comment: @SalvadorDalí - The *purpose* of a class having a pure virtual function is to ensure that a base class cannot be instantiated and that any derived classes cannot be instantiated unless they override that function (and don't override in a way that keeps it pure).   Having a requirement to create an instance of a class with a pure virtual is therefore a sign of a flawed design.   A requirement for a class to have a pure virtual function and a requirement to instantiate that class are mutually exclusive (only one of those requirements can be met, both can never be met together).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. How would I refactor the code, so that I can still achieve the same thing? Anything in coding is possible right, haha.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare abstract class in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502488/declare-abstract-class-in-c)

Comment: Refactoring code is not enough.   You either need to remove the requirement that a class have a pure virtual function or remove the requirement to create an instance of it.   And there are plenty of things that can't be done in code - in your case, a code construct that is used to deliberately prevent "X" from happening and another code construct that attempts to deliberately make "X" happen can't both be valid.

Comment: My advice is to spend 20 to 30 minutes and produce a [mcve] and ask a brand new question on how to refactor the code. I think you have an XY problem but its difficult to tell how best to approach the situation without a reasonable code example.

Comment: What do you mean with an XY problem? Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 3):

When you create an abstract `class` you are telling the compiler that there is no reason to create an instance of the class itself. This is usually done when you define an interface - set of methods and or fields for a base `class` that should work for various inherited classes but not base itself. So compiler helps you to avoid unintentional mistakes and does not allow to create an instance. So there are 2 possible solutions:

1. you made your `class` abstract by mistake and it should not be. Solution is simple just make all virtual functions not pure and implement them
2. your `class` should be abstract indeed. Then you should not have instance of the class, static or not. Usually when you have interface you work with pointer or reference to the base class and assign them to derived class that implements the interface. What should be done in your case is not clear as we do not have enough information, simplest in your case to make that static variable a pointer (probably a smart one) and assign it to an instance to derived class somewhere.

Comment: A class is allowed to define (implement) a pure virtual function - and doing so, does not make that function "not pure".    The point of a pure virtual function is that it must be overridden by a derived class, otherwise that derived class also cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Peter good point, changed wording to make it less confusing. Thanks.